# Are there any benefits to buying high write speed Blu-ray disks?

Tags: blu-ray, bitrate

There are many different type of blu ray disc out there, the hestitation to buy was started from read/write speed of a blu ray disc.
I'm looking for Verbatim/Memorex/Sony disc, the most common read write speed is 4/6/8x. AFAIK 1x speed represents 36Mbit/s, where 4x=144Mbit/s, 6x=216Mbit/s and so on. 
Since I want to burn many episodes in a single disc, 2x speed is enough to save space and money. 
Question: Do you recommend me to buy higher write speed disc(4x,6x,8x) even though the content bitrate is roughly 4-8Mbit/s. 
Thanks. 
*Note: If this question is not related to Superuser, please suggest a place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The write speed supported by the media is unrelated to what it can be used for. Assuming the write process is good enough, it is also unrelated to the attainable read speeds. I have old 2x and 4x CD-Rs that were recorded way back in the proverbial middle ages, and they read back a lot faster than that on modern, fast readers (though, due to media degredation, usually not at full speed).

So no, **buying media that supports a higher write speed presents no direct benefit *if*** you can live with simply the write taking longer. But since Blu-ray (just like CDs and DVDs) is a [WORM (Write Once, Read Many)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) type media, write speeds should not be much of a concern unless you are writing a large number of disks. **The media can be used for the same purposes,** regardless of its maximum rated write speed; like with CDs and DVDs, the *read* speed is limited primarily by the device used for reading the disks, and secondarily by the quality of the recording (which is impacted by things like the specific dye composition, recording speed used, media deterioration, and more).

Using media rated for a higher maximum write speed, and actually recording the media at that higher speed, means that the write process will finish sooner than if you used media that required writing at a slower speed. Media rated for a higher maximum write speed within the same quality range is usually more expensive at any given time; hence, the faster write speed comes at a direct monetary cost. The issue here is whether **the time savings when recording the media offsets the additional expense of the "faster" media.** That is a judgement you will have to make for yourself; we cannot make it for you, and any question here on the *outcome* of such a judgement would highly likely be closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Higher rated write speeds *may* be related to higher quality media, but that is not guaranteed. If you want higher quality media, then buy from reputable vendors with solid reputations rather than blindly looking for the highest rated write speed. Since product recommendations are off topic here, I will refrain from guessing which vendors that might be.

Comment: So do you mean if there are 2 choices for you to choose from, 4x and 6x, you will choose 4x?

Comment: @darkfang *Not necessarily.* I am saying that if the choices are (to borrow your examples) 4x and 6x, *the two can be used for the same purposes.* If you are okay with the write taking longer, buying merely faster media does not provide any direct benefit other than the write process completing sooner. Whether the faster write process is worth the usually additional expense is a judgement we cannot make for you. In most situations, I would rather buy higher quality media that is rated for a lower maximum write speed, than lower quality media that is rated for a higher maximum write speed.

Comment: Ohhh now i see...